# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at loading screen

Tags: boot, 18.04

After battling a black screen and a boot loop I was able to boot my PC successfully. After using it a couple days, I understood that it doesn't connect to the internet anymore. And by that I mean it could ping 8.8.8.8 but none of the apps including the browser could connect to anything. I could not update any of the apps either as the update module gave me an error for unmet dependencies. 
I tried a couple fixes without success.

I decided to say f it and install it fresh after backing up my files. Now that I'm trying to boot my PC and it's not going past the logo screen. What is the fix?

Answer (score 1):

- Just restart your laptop and at the time of boot enter into bios menu by pressing F10 or Fn+f10.
- At bios menu look for **boot mode** and change to **UEFI ONLY**.
- Then restart your problem should be solved by this.